# function name, "onButtonClick" or "onClickButton"

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I am Japanese Web developer.

I want to be better at English.

What is the proper name of a function that means, "when button is(was) clicked" ?

"onButtonClick"?

"onClickButton"?

"onButtonClicked"?

"onClickedButton"?

I like "onButtonClick" then "onClickButton", "onButtonClicked" then "onClickedButton".

Comment: I don't think there's one "proper" way to write them or a convention. Also not something to ask on stackoverflow, try Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Picking the correct name is a difficult part of programming. This question might get better answers at https://english.stackexchange.com/ provided that you read their tour and make sure it is on topic over there. Here is is likely to be considered off topic because it is an opinion based question.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will ask same question there!!!

Comment: @akao Even as a native English speaker, it can be hard to give good variable names too. It is in fact a common problem faced among developers.. Ganbatte kudasai! :)

Comment: @wentjun
Thank you.
Well, then even there in no correct, which is your favorite?

Comment: @akao I'll pick `onButtonClick`. I choose not to include any tenses on it, because 'click' is an action verb, thus 'button click' will seem more descriptive and appropraite.

Comment: Thank you so much. Well,  "not to include any tenses on it" ← you mean it is better to say "click" rather than "clicked"? How about "onButtonClick" or "onClickButton", which do you prefer?

Comment: @arieljuod There's no code here to review, so this would not be a suitable question for Code Review — at least not in this form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “onButtonClick” or “onClickButton"

[**Note** to others: This question was also asked on English.SE, it is an explanation for someone whose first language is not English; and wants help naming functions.]

Read one word at a time, left to right. The first capitalised word is the object or action. The first word "on" means it's a handler, the second word is the action or object.

The '*object first*' word goes ***on*** the object. The '*action first*' word goes ***on*** the action.

The button might have an onButtonClick() function which might call an onClickButton() function ***if*** you want clicks on the button to be handled. The second function isn't mandatory, the first function is likely defined for the GUI you are under (in its header files).

---

Button is an object and click is an action. Neither is the  only possibility.

For example you could have objects called: buttons, images, thumbnails (tiny images) and text. For possible actions you could have: click and hover.

There are more possibilities than what is listed above but let's keep it fairly simple.

So when you have a button or image or thumbnail or text (just one word in a sentence) let's assume that you can: roll your mouse across the screen without acting on any of those objects, click on something, or pause your mouse over something but not click on it (hover).

Now let's assume somewhere there is a "Button". **When** you do *something* to the button it is "onButton". **What** you do to the button comes next, you can click or hover, unless you do neither.

If you click, you "onButtonclick", and if you hover, you "onButtonHover".

Hopefully that is clear thus far.

Now ***when*** you "onButtonClick" or "onButtonHover" you can choose to fire a handler to do something as the result of your action, you can also ignore it and do nothing.

**If** you choose to handle it then ***that's*** an "onClick" or "onHover".

The onClick() or onHover() function (if it exists) can do *something*. Perhaps when you hover you would like to highlight, maybe not. Perhaps when you click there's an activity (an action) you want, maybe not.

So the onClick() function **might** have to handle (take an action for) clicks made on buttons or images or thumbnails or text (one word), same for an onHover() function that you may or may not have.

Follow, so far?

So, the onClick() function might have an onClickButton, onClickImage, onClickThumbnail and onClickText subroutine (all, any or even none of them).

See also: "[Create your own controls - the art of subclassing](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/480/Create-your-own-controls-the-art-of-subclassing?msg=3819620)"

The word “onButtonClicked” returns ~22,000 search results, the word “onClickedButton” ~608 results, “onButtonClick" ~122,000, and “onClickButton" ~27,600. It is clear what is preferred.

Comment: Thank you so much. I need little bit time to understand this.

Do you mean like, if you write event on a element , like

<button @click="onButtonClick">

,
a action is always about the button.
So the word "button" should come before the word "click" ?

Comment: And we may write like this?

onButtonClick () {

  onClickButton();
  onHoverButton();

};